# Jface dialog with ScrolledComposite

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I am trying to display scrollable composite in my dialog window.

But it do not get the scrollbars. I also don't get the "OK" "Cancel" buttons.

How to fix it?

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog {

  public MyDialog (Shell parentShell) {
    super(parentShell);     
  }

   protected void configureShell(Shell newShell) {
    super.configureShell(newShell);
    newShell.setText("test");
    newShell.setSize(200, 100);
  }

  protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
         ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.H_SCROLL |    SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);


    Composite composite = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
    composite.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

    new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("1111");
    new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("2222");
    new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("3333");
    new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("4444");
    new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("5555");
    new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("6666");
    new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("7777");

    sc.setContent(composite);
    sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    sc.setExpandVertical(true);


    return parent;  


  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I almost got it working. However, at the bottom there is some empty space where the dialog buttons would be. If this doesn't bother you, or you are going to add buttons, the code below will do what you want. If not, I don't know how to help you.

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog
{

    protected MyDialog(Shell parentShell) {
        super(parentShell);
    }

    protected void configureShell(Shell newShell) {
        super.configureShell(newShell);
        newShell.setText("test");
        newShell.setSize(200, 100);
    }

    protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
    }

    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
        Composite content = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
        content.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(content, SWT.H_SCROLL
                | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);

        Composite composite = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
        composite.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

        new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("1111");
        new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("2222");
        new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("3333");
        new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("4444");
        new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("5555");
        new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("6666");
        new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("7777");

        sc.setContent(composite);
        sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
        sc.setExpandVertical(true);
        sc.setMinSize(composite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));

        return parent; 
      }
}
```

[image]

However, I assume you are going to use dialog buttons. Otherwise you could simply use a shell with a composite as seen in the example I posted before...

Comment: @user1658192 Remove this line in addition: `newShell.setSize(200, 100);`

Comment: @user1658192 Try the code example I provided. Does this work for you?

Comment: I believe it will work without the dialog as you did. I need it to work in dialog

Comment: @user1658192 I understood that. I'm trying to narrow down your problem... So you tried it and it works?

Comment: this worked for me! the only change is `Composite content = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);` why `new Composite(...)` didn't work?

Comment: @user1658192 I'm not sure. It worked in the simple example I posted... Must be something about JFace Dialog. Anyhow, glad I could help. Please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: "Consider accepting my answer"?? Ofcourse i will accept it! I was just waiting to answer my comment

Comment: I was wondering, is the FillLayout crucial to get this to work? (Using a grid layout now, and having problems ...).