# java composite with an scrolling image

Tags: java, image, scroll, swt, composite

I am newbie with swt and I have a Dialog that contains an image but if the image is too big is not possible to see the complete image. It is cut. So I decided to create a Dialog with scrolling. I have done but the scroll doesn't work. It appears and you can clic over and move it but I can't move over the image. I have tried several things but none of them work :(

```
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
    //getShell().setText(Messages.labelTitle);
    //setTitleImage(image); // Image to be displayed in your Dialog
    //return parent;

    Composite container = new Composite(getShell(), SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    container.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    Label preview = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
    GridData layoutData = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
    preview.setLayoutData(layoutData);
    preview.setImage(image);

    return parent;      
}
```

Comment: You need to look at `ScrolledComposite`. Also your `Composite` has the wrong parent - it should be the  `parent`.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12660985) for an example with a `Dialog` and a `ScrolledComposite`.